# How to go back to a non-blank page only in webview history?

Tags: android, android-webview

I used to use `onPageFinished` to keep track of webview history:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if ("about:blank".equals(url) && view.getTag() != null){
        view.loadUrl(view.getTag().toString());
    }else{ 
        view.setTag(url);
    }
}
```

now, when I try `view.goBack()` it goes back to about:blank and not to the page I want.

How can I set that "about:blank" url so to be put into webview history, so that when I go back I don't see it again. But I don't want `view.clearHistory()`, because it deletes all history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well assuming you want to go back in the history until you find the first non *about:blank*
here is how to do it:

in your activity

```
 public void goBackInWebView(){
    WebBackForwardList history = webView.copyBackForwardList();
    int index = -1;
    String url = null;

    while (webView.canGoBackOrForward(index)) {
          if (!history.getItemAtIndex(history.getCurrentIndex() + index).getUrl().equals("about:blank")) {
             webView.goBackOrForward(index);
             url = history.getItemAtIndex(-index).getUrl();
             Log.e("tag","first non empty" + url);
             break;
           }
           index --;

    }
   // no history found that is not empty
   if (url == null) {
      finish();
   }
```

}

code logic is to loop throw all previous pages. and on first no empty page load it.
if nothing found finish the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way of editing the history stack directly, but you could maybe fashion something with [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

From the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) documentation:

> A WebView has several customization points where you can add your own behavior. These are:
>
> ...
>
> Creating and setting a WebViewClient subclass. It will be called when
> things happen that impact the rendering of the content, eg, errors or
> form submissions. **You can also intercept URL loading here** (via
> shouldOverrideUrlLoading()).

Answer (score 0):

I found @Mr.Me's answer to be a bit nicer as an OnKeyListener

```
public class BackButtonListener implements View.OnKeyListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) v;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    WebBackForwardList backstack = webView.copyBackForwardList();
                    int currentIndex = backstack.getCurrentIndex();
                    int i = -1;
                    while (webView.canGoBackOrForward(i)) {
                        if (!backstack.getItemAtIndex(currentIndex + i).getUrl().equals("about:blank")) {
                            webView.goBackOrForward(i);
                            return true;
                        }
                        i--;
                    }
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which you just set like so:

```
mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new BackButtonListener());
```